# коварный столбец rownum

Tags: sql, oracle

Пусть имеется большое кол-во таблиц *Am* с большим кол-вом строк, где *m* - некоторый индекс. Делаю я такой запрос :

```
SELECT * FROM A1, A2, ... An WHERE ROWNUM < 2;
```

И мой запрос встает. По логике, бд должна выбрать первые строки из каждой таблицы, собрать их в одну, присвоить 1 и вывести. Почему запрос выполняется слишком долго?

Comment: Смотрите план выполнения. Если она решила идти по nested loops то может и сделает как кажется логичным. Но что то мне подсказывает, что оптимизатор не оптимален :) Можете еще попробовать хинт `/*+ FIRST_ROWS*/`

Comment: @Mike не помогает хинт

Comment: Пути оракла не исповедимы :) Боюсь единственный ответ на ваш вопрос - потому что ему так хочется. И если это практический вопрос, то видимо надо искать другие пути вместо rownum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По логике базы данных все выглядит иначе.  В запросе происходит декартово произведение, все строки всех таблиц перемножаются друг на друга, потому что в секции where/join не указаны условия соединения таблиц. После того, как строки объединятся во всевозможных комбинациях, будет взята первая строчка.
Именно поэтому так долго. Проблему можно решить несколькими методами, самый простой - заменить перечисление таблиц на подзапросы:

```
select * 
from 
    (select * from a1 where rownum < 2), 
    (select * from a2 where rownum < 2)...
```